# Launch .exportedUI on workbook open

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I've created a workbook with VBA that is launched from buttons contained in a custom UI. However the workbook exists on a virtual network so the custom UI is lost on log on. I'm hoping someone can help me with some VBA that will launch the custom UI without resorting to creating a separate XML script that reproduces the UI customisations every time. The reason for this is I don't have an xml editor and can't get hold of one on my work machine.

The workbook location is static, I don't need it to be portable and so I'm happy that the solution involves importing the .exportedUI file from the same location as the workbook each time the workbook is opened. It would also be useful if the custom UI features were removed on workbook close.

So I have the following worksheet:

```
K:\Sharedlocation\sharedfolder\workbook.xlsm
```

Stored alongside:

```
K:\Sharedlocation\sharedfolder\Export.exportedUI
```

I'd like the workbook to import Export.exportedUI and parse it so that the UI is customised.

If you can help that would be great.

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

```
<mso:cmd app="Excel" dt="1" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:x1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui/macro" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
 <mso:ribbon>
  <mso:qat/>
   <mso:tabs>
    <mso:tab id="mso_c1.1416871F" label="CRM" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabInsert">
    <mso:group id="mso_c2.1416871F" label="Activity" autoScale="true">
     <mso:button idQ="x1:K:_MOL_Enquiry_Team_Leads_and_Pipeline_Pipeline_Manager_Test_Account.xlsm_Add_Call_0_143AA844" label="Add Call" imageMso="AutoDial" onAction="K:\MOL_Enquiry_Team\Leads and Pipeline\Pipeline Manager Test Account.xlsm!Add_Call" visible="true"/>
     <mso:button idQ="x1:K:_MOL_Enquiry_Team_Leads_and_Pipeline_Pipeline_Manager_Test_Account.xlsm_Add_Email_1_143AA844" label="Add Email" imageMso="GoToMail" onAction="K:\MOL_Enquiry_Team\Leads and Pipeline\Pipeline Manager Test Account.xlsm!Add_Email" visible="true"/>
     <mso:button idQ="x1:K:_MOL_Enquiry_Team_Leads_and_Pipeline_Pipeline_Manager_Test_Account.xlsm_Add_Meeting_2_143AA844" label="Add Meeting" imageMso="CondolatoryEvent" onAction="K:\MOL_Enquiry_Team\Leads and Pipeline\Pipeline Manager Test Account.xlsm!Add_Meeting" visible="true"/>
    </mso:group>
    <mso:group id="mso_c1.1439428A" label="Contacts" imageMso="SlideMasterClipArtPlaceholderInsert" autoScale="true">
     <mso:button idQ="x1:K:_MOL_Enquiry_Team_Leads_and_Pipeline_Pipeline_Manager_Test_Account.xlsm_New_Contact_3_143AA844" label="New Contact" imageMso="SlideMasterClipArtPlaceholderInsert" onAction="K:\MOL_Enquiry_Team\Leads and Pipeline\Pipeline Manager Test Account.xlsm!New_Contact" visible="true"/>
    </mso:group>
   </mso:tab>
  </mso:tabs>
 </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

Comment: See if this webpage helps : http://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html#readcode

Answer (score -1):

Just worked on project like this for friend over the weekend.  See code below

```
'add reference Microsoft XML, v6.0
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim objWHTTP As Object
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    Dim lngFreeFile As Long



    On Error Resume Next
        Set objWHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set objWHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    URL = "Enter your URL here"

    objWHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objWHTTP.send
    arrData = objWHTTP.responseBody
    strData = StrConv(arrData, vbUnicode)

    Dim xmlbook As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    xmlbook.LoadXML strData

    Dim datasht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       If sht.Name = "Data" Then
          Set datasht = sht
          Exit For
       End If
    Next sht
    If datasht Is Nothing Then
       Sheets.Add before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Data"
       Set datasht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    End If

    With datasht
       .Cells.Clear

        'Enter each date uniquely in column A
        Set myTag = xmlbook.getElementsByTagName(tagName:="put your tag here")
        Dim row As IXMLDOMElement

        For Each row In myTag
           'enter your code here
        nex row
    End With
End Sub
​
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the response. I'm puzzled on a couple of bits:

What does the URL refer to?
"For Each row In myTag 'enter your code here" does this refer to the xml code in .exportedUI document? Otherwise I'm not sure.
Would you mind providing a bit more annotation? I'm afraid my knowledge is well below your level (I'm working on improving it though!).

Comment: I assumed the file on K:\ was xml.   The URL can be either on the web (http) or a file.  getElementsByTagName() creates a NodeList() which can be enumerated in a for loop.  Would be helpful to see the xml.

Comment: Hi Jdweng, I've posted the xml code contained in the exported.UI file as an answer above. Hope that's OK. Let me know if that helps. Cheers.